# cometchat method not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cometchat

**checkCometChatUrl** block is not execute with success or failure. my code is bellow.

```c
    #import <MessageSDKFramework/CometChat.h>
    #import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

    @interface LoginVC ()<UITextFieldDelegate>
    {
        CometChat *cometChat;

    }

    @end

    @implementation LoginVC

    - (void)viewDidLoad{

        [super viewDidLoad];

        [cometChat checkCometChatUrl:@"https://cisner.com" success:^(NSDictionary *response) {
            NSLog(@"%@", response);

        //code not execute here

        } failure:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
          //code not execute here
        }];
        }
```

Comment: checkCometChatUrl is deprecated. kindly update the cometchat version. or contact cometchat customer support.

Comment: I have use another bellow method but not execute block.

             [cometChat login:@"devcisner" password:@"123456" success:^(NSDictionary *response) {
                 NSLog(@"test");
             } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"test");
             }];

Comment: you are getting any errors ?

Comment: not execute any block success/failure.

Comment: @user3091160 Did you initialize `cometChat` before using it? Are you sure that `cometChat` isn't `nil` when you call method?

Comment: initialize with bellow method but still not response in any block success/failure.

 [cometChat initializeCometChat:@"..." licenseKey:@"...." apikey:@"......" isCometOnDemand:YES
                         success:^(NSDictionary *response) {
                             NSLog(@"%@", response);
                            
                         } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                             NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
                             
                            
                         }];

Answer (score -3, accepted):

@cometchat responce.....

Our team is already looking at your concern, which we believe is from Web end not from iOS SDK.

Comment: cometchat team not installed properly his framework that's way not getting response.

I believe that this framework is not used.

This SDK will slow down the development speed of your Project.

Comment: So which SDK then you decided to use?

Comment: As per my opinion you can use Qickblox ya Firebase. 

you could use any other SDK according to your budget.  because Qickblox is costly for lifetime Plan.